# files duplication in java

Tags: java, swing, file, jlist

I have added a few files into my `JList` via `JFileChooser` using a `vector`. I am trying to make it systematically by checking if the particular files are available in the `JList` or not. For example, if I add a file named 'abc.xml', I immediately check if that file exists in the `JList` or not.

Also I would like to check if the file is repeated only once. If it is repeated more than once ('abc.xml', 'abc.xml',...), there should be an error message indicating that the file is added more than once.

I am posting my complete code here;

```
         public Test() 
{
    setTitle("EXAMPLE");
    getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][][][][grow][][][][][][][]
               [][][grow][grow][][][grow][][][][][][][grow]", "[][][][][][][][grow]
              [grow][][][][][][][grow][]"));

    final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    getContentPane().add(fileChooser, "cell 0 1 3 16");

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane, "cell 23 2 3 15,grow");

    vector = new Vector<File>();
    final JList list = new JList(vector);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(list);


    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton(" Add          ");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (File file : fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
                        vector.addElement(file);
                 }
                //System.out.println("Added..!!");
                list.updateUI();

            }
    });
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, "cell 4 0");



    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton(" Remove   ");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(list.getSelectedIndices().length > 0) {
                  int[] selectedIndices = list.getSelectedIndices();
                  for (int i = selectedIndices.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                        vector.removeElementAt(i);
                    } 
                   }
                    //System.out.println("Removed..!!");
                    list.updateUI();

        }   
        });
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1, "cell 4 2");

    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton(" Check       ");
    btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ***File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            boolean found = false;
            for (File f : vector) {
                 if (file.getName().equals(f.getName())) {
                     found = true;
                     break;
                 }
            }
            if (!found) {
                vector.add(file);
                fireIntervalAdded(this, vector.size()-1, vector.size()-1);
            } else {
                // Abusive usage of an exception
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File " + file.getName() + " 
                already added");

            }***
         });

           public static void main(String args[]) {        
          // Create an instance of the test application         
           Test mainFrame = new Test();        
           mainFrame.pack();         
           mainFrame.setVisible(true);     
  }
```

What i get is, a msg box telling that the file is added already even when the file occurs only once.

What I expect is, when the file is added once, it should not display anything. But when it is added more than once, only then it should display a msg that the file is already added.

Can somebody help?

Comment: aaaaah!  the (code formatting) horror!

Comment: Code does not look anything near what you want to do? Can you format it for readability purposes?

Comment: Do you want me to post the entire code? if so, I can do it.

Comment: OP please, I went into the guts of your code and formatted it. Now respect that and edit this version.

Comment: Yes, Saw your edits..! I have added a few lines to it now.

Comment: It would really help if you posted an SSCCE http://sscce.org Just like that, I don't get what the last code-block is supposed to do. You already perform a check in the previous block (I suppose that abc.xml was just an example)

Comment: I have removed the last piece of code now, since it was just a try, and t dint actually work.

Answer (score 3):

OK, Here is an example of something you describe. I am not quite sure what is the condition to refuse to add a File. This one is based on name, but I am wondering if you are not looking for a `File.equals()` using first `getCanonicalFile()`. I showed that in comment in the code too.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class MyListModel extends AbstractListModel {

        private Vector<File> files = new Vector<File>();

        public void addFilesToModel(File[] f) {
            for (File file : f) {
                addFileToModel(file);
            }
        }

        public void addFileToModel(File file) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            boolean found = false;
            // file = file.getCanonicalFile();
            for (File file2 : files) {
                // file2.getCanonicalFile().equals(file) + throw IOException
                if (file2.getName().equals(file.getName())) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                files.add(file);
                fireIntervalAdded(this, files.size() - 1, files.size() - 1);
            } else {
                // Abusive usage of an exception
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("File " + file.getName() + " already added");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return files.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return files.get(index);
        }

    }

    private static File lastFolder;

    protected static void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final MyListModel model = new MyListModel();
        JList list = new JList(model);
        final JButton button = new JButton("Add files...");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                if (lastFolder != null) {
                    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(lastFolder);
                }
                chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                chooser.showDialog(button, "Add files");
                if (chooser.getSelectedFiles() != null) {
                    for (File file : chooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
                        try {
                            model.addFileToModel(file);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, e1.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                    lastFolder = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

EDIT

---

Besides the fact that your code was incomplete, I managed to arrange it and make it work but it is really far from perfect. I also got rid of the MigLayout because it requires an additional library. Feel free to put it back.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    Vector<File> vector;
    JPanel root;
    private MyListModel model;

    public class MyListModel extends AbstractListModel {

        public void addFilesToModel(File[] f) {
            for (File file : f) {
                addFileToModel(file);
            }
        }

        public void addFileToModel(File file) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            boolean found = false;
            // file = file.getCanonicalFile();
            for (File file2 : vector) {
                // file2.getCanonicalFile().equals(file) + throw IOException
                if (file2.getName().equals(file.getName())) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                vector.add(file);
                fireIntervalAdded(this, vector.size() - 1, vector.size() - 1);
            } else {
                // Abusive usage of an exception
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("File " + file.getName() + " already added");
            }
        }

        public void removeFileFromModel(File file) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            int index = vector.indexOf(file);
            File removed = vector.remove(index);
            if (removed != null) {
                fireIntervalRemoved(this, index, index);
            } else {
                // Nothing was removed
            }
        }

        public void removeFilesFromModel(File[] files) {
            for (File f : files) {
                removeFileFromModel(f);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return vector.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return vector.get(index);
        }

    }

    public Test() {
        super("EXAMPLE");
        root = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        vector = new Vector<File>();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        getContentPane().add(root);
        final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        root.add(fileChooser, gbc);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.ipadx = 5;
        gbc.ipady = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 1;

        vector = new Vector<File>();
        model = new MyListModel();
        final JList list = new JList(model);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        root.add(scrollPane, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        final JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (File file : fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
                    try {
                        model.addFileToModel(file);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                        showError(btnNewButton, file);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        root.add(btnNewButton, gbc);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Remove");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (list.getSelectedIndices().length > 0) {
                    for (Object file : list.getSelectedValues()) {
                        model.removeFileFromModel((File) file);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        gbc.gridx++;
        root.add(btnNewButton_1, gbc);

        final JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Check");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                boolean found = false;
                for (File f : vector) {
                    if (file.getName().equals(f.getName())) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    showError(btnNewButton_2, file);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnNewButton_2, "File " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " is not in the list yet");
                }
            }

        });
        gbc.gridx++;
        root.add(btnNewButton_2, gbc);
    }

    private void showError(Component parent, File file) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "File " + file.getName() + " already added");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test mainFrame = new Test();
                mainFrame.pack();
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example. But now, I have modified my code to show what i gave and what I get. It would be great if you could help.

Comment: @dmurali 1) You never do anything with the result of this line `boolean abcExists = vector.contains(file);` 2) Why do you keep on hard-coding "abc.txt"? I understood that you wanted to add files in the list but just make sure it is not added twice. Your code prevents any file named "abc.txt" from being added. 3) Do you want to only compare files based on their name, or should it be possible to add `C:\tmp.log` and `C:\foo\tmp.log`?

Comment: I would want to compare files just using their names. for eg; C:\tmp.log = C:\foo\tmp.log since the file is still the same

Comment: I have removed boolean abcExists, which is not being used and also changed "abc.txt" to file.getName().equals(f.getName())

Comment: @dmurali C:\tmp.log = C:\foo\tmp.log is actually not the same. One is inside the "foo" folder while the other is a the root of "C:". In you code, indeed replace the condition with "file.getName().equals(f.getName())". Below, uncomment this line `// vector.add(file);` and change the next line to this `fireIntervalAdded(this, vector.size()-1, vector.length()-1);`. `file.length()`is the size of the selected file!

Comment: Yes, I have uncommented vector.add(file) and also added the next line, but it does not consider file.length(), asking if i have to add cast to vector.

Comment: @dmurali Sorry there was a typo. You should use only vector.size(): fireIntervalAdded(this, vector.size()-1, vector.size()-1);

Comment: Yes, but still, the msg remains the same. It gives a msg that the file is already added even when it is added only once. I have edited my above code(last part of the original code) for reference.!

Comment: To be more precise, I have a button named 'CHECK'. I add a file and click the 'check' button to confirm its existence. So when I click the button and when a file is existing only once, I get a msg telling telling that the file is already existing.

Comment: @dmurali You should update your question by posting a complete, working code, with a main() method. It would allow us to review your code and see what is not working. Posting bits and pieces, and trying to perform pacthes here and there is obviously not sufficient

Comment: @dmurali I added a fixed version of your code at the end of my post but it is really far from being perfect. Hopefully, you will understand better what you are doing.

Comment: Thanx for your code, but this does not solve my purpose. this just tells the user that the file is in the list. But what i expect is that the file should not be added more than once. when the same file is added more than once, we should get an error msg telling that teh file is already existing.

Comment: @dmurali this is what the code does. If I add the same file twice I get a warning and the file is not re-added.

Comment: Anyways thanks a lot for your guidance..! i will solve this now.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector.contains(fileName)
```

start with that first?